# How to synchronize loading of textures to the GPU while the main rendering loop is running

Tags: c++, vulkan

I wish to periodically upload images to the GPU (depending on user input) while my main rendering loop is running.

My current implementation works fine if the image uploading is not done asynchronously (but this will cause the application to lag while the images are uploaded)

When the data transfer is done asynchronously, the implementation will sometimes crash on vkQueueSubmit(), likely because of a lack of synchronization between the thread uploading the images to the GPU, and the main rendering loop.

What is the correct way to apply synchronization to this?

Probable issue:

- I record command buffers in the main loop and also in the image uploading process. What kind of synchronization is needed to allow this?

**Main Rendering Loop**

```
void App::drawFrame()
{
    inFlightFences_[currentFrame_].wait();

    uint32_t imageIndex;
    VkResult result = vkAcquireNextImageKHR(vulkanLogicalDevice_->handle(), vulkanSwapChain_.handle(), std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max(), imageAvailableSemaphores_[currentFrame_].handle(), VK_NULL_HANDLE, &imageIndex);

    if (result == VK_ERROR_OUT_OF_DATE_KHR) {
        recreateSwapChain();
        return;
    }
    else if (result != VK_SUCCESS && result != VK_SUBOPTIMAL_KHR) {
        throw std::runtime_error("failed to acquire swap chain image!");
    }

    updateUniformBuffer(imageIndex);
    vulkanCommandBuffers_.recordCommandBuffer(imageIndex, swapChainFrameBuffers_, vulkanRenderPass_, vulkanSwapChain_, vulkanGraphicsPipeline_, vulkanVertexBuffer_, vulkanIndexBuffer_, vulkanDescriptorSets_);    

    VkSubmitInfo submitInfo = {};
    submitInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SUBMIT_INFO;

    VkSemaphore waitSemaphores[] = { imageAvailableSemaphores_[currentFrame_].handle() };
    VkPipelineStageFlags waitStages[] = { VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT };
    submitInfo.waitSemaphoreCount = 1;
    submitInfo.pWaitSemaphores = waitSemaphores;
    submitInfo.pWaitDstStageMask = waitStages;
    submitInfo.commandBufferCount = 1;
    submitInfo.pCommandBuffers = &vulkanCommandBuffers_[imageIndex];

    VkSemaphore signalSemaphores[] = { renderFinishedSemaphores_[currentFrame_].handle() };
    submitInfo.signalSemaphoreCount = 1;
    submitInfo.pSignalSemaphores = signalSemaphores;

    inFlightFences_[currentFrame_].reset(); // vkResetFences(vulkanLogicalDevice_->handle(), 1, &inFlightFences[currentFrame]);

    if (vkQueueSubmit(vulkanLogicalDevice_->getGraphicsQueue(), 1, &submitInfo, inFlightFences_[currentFrame_].handle()) != VK_SUCCESS) {
        throw std::runtime_error("failed to submit draw command buffer!");
    }

    VkPresentInfoKHR presentInfo = {};
    presentInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PRESENT_INFO_KHR;
    presentInfo.waitSemaphoreCount = 1;
    presentInfo.pWaitSemaphores = signalSemaphores;

    VkSwapchainKHR swapChains[] = { vulkanSwapChain_.handle() };
    presentInfo.swapchainCount = 1;
    presentInfo.pSwapchains = swapChains;

    presentInfo.pImageIndices = &imageIndex;

    result = vkQueuePresentKHR(vulkanLogicalDevice_->getPresentQueue(), &presentInfo);

    if (result == VK_ERROR_OUT_OF_DATE_KHR || result == VK_SUBOPTIMAL_KHR || window_.frameBufferResized()) {
        window_.setFrameBufferResized(false);
        recreateSwapChain();
    }
    else if (result != VK_SUCCESS) {
        throw std::runtime_error("failed to present swap chain image!");
    }

    currentFrame_ = (currentFrame_ + 1) % MAX_FRAMES_IN_FLIGHT;
}
```

**On user input, upload images:**

```
ThreadPool::get().run([files, this]() {
            for (auto &filename : files)
            {
                Texture texture(filename);
                VulkanTexture fullImage(parent_->logicalDevice(), texture, *(parent_->physicalDevice()), *(parent_->commandPool()));
                GuiTexture smallImage(parent_->logicalDevice(), parent_->physicalDevice(), parent_->commandPool(), filename, fullImage.vulkanImage(), 400, 400);
                parent_->guiImage().push_back(std::move(smallImage));
            }
        });
```

class Texture just loads an image from file to CPU ram

```
VulkanTexture::VulkanTexture(const std::shared_ptr<VulkanLogicalDevice>& logicalDevice, const VulkanPhysicalDevice &physicalDevice, const VulkanCommandPool &commandPool, const VulkanImage & sourceImage, uint32_t width, uint32_t height)
    : logicalDevice_(logicalDevice)
{
    vulkanImage_ = VulkanImage(logicalDevice, width, height, VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM, VK_IMAGE_TILING_OPTIMAL, VK_IMAGE_USAGE_TRANSFER_DST_BIT | VK_IMAGE_USAGE_SAMPLED_BIT);
    deviceMemory_ = VulkanDeviceMemory(logicalDevice, vulkanImage_, physicalDevice, VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT);

    vulkanImage_.transitionImageLayout(commandPool, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL); // transitionImageLayout(textureImage, VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL);
    vulkanImage_.copyImageToImage(sourceImage, commandPool, VK_FILTER_NEAREST);
    vulkanImage_.transitionImageLayout(commandPool, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL); //transitionImageLayout(textureImage, VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL);
}

GuiTexture::GuiTexture(const std::shared_ptr<VulkanLogicalDevice>& logicalDevice, const std::shared_ptr < VulkanPhysicalDevice > & physicalDevice, const std::shared_ptr<VulkanCommandPool>& commandPool, const std::string &filePath, const VulkanImage &sourceImage, uint32_t width, uint32_t height)
    : texture_(logicalDevice, *physicalDevice, *commandPool, sourceImage, width, height)
    , sampler_(logicalDevice)
    , imgView_(logicalDevice, texture_.handle(), VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM) // VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM??
    , imGuiTexture_(nullptr)
    , filePath_(filePath)
{
    imGuiTexture_ = ImGui_ImplGlfwVulkan_AddTexture(sampler_.handle(), imgView_.handle());
}


VulkanImage::VulkanImage(const std::shared_ptr<VulkanLogicalDevice>& logicalDevice, uint32_t width, uint32_t height, VkFormat format, VkImageTiling tiling, VkImageUsageFlags usage)
    : logicalDevice_(logicalDevice)
    , image_(VK_NULL_HANDLE)
    , imageInfo_({})
    , vkImageLayout_(VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED)
{
    imageInfo_.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_CREATE_INFO;
    imageInfo_.imageType = VK_IMAGE_TYPE_2D;
    imageInfo_.extent.width = width;
    imageInfo_.extent.height = height;
    imageInfo_.extent.depth = 1;
    imageInfo_.mipLevels = 1;
    imageInfo_.arrayLayers = 1;
    imageInfo_.format = format;
    imageInfo_.tiling = tiling;
    imageInfo_.initialLayout = vkImageLayout_ = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED;
    imageInfo_.usage = usage;
    imageInfo_.samples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT;
    imageInfo_.sharingMode = VK_SHARING_MODE_EXCLUSIVE;

    if (vkCreateImage(logicalDevice->handle(), &imageInfo_, nullptr, &image_) != VK_SUCCESS) {
        throw std::runtime_error("failed to create image!");
    }
}

void VulkanDeviceMemory::copyToGpu(void * cpuMemory, VkDeviceSize numBytes)
{
    void* gpuMemory;
    vkMapMemory(logicalDevice_->handle(), deviceMemory_, 0, numBytes, 0, &gpuMemory); // buffer.getBufferInfo().size
    memcpy(gpuMemory, cpuMemory, numBytes); // (size_t)vertexBuffer_.getBufferInfo().size
    vkUnmapMemory(logicalDevice_->handle(), deviceMemory_);
}


void VulkanImage::transitionImageLayout(const VulkanCommandPool & commandPool, VkImageLayout newLayout)
{
    VkCommandBuffer commandBuffer = commandPool.beginSingleTimeCommands();

    VkImageMemoryBarrier barrier = {};
    barrier.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_MEMORY_BARRIER;
    barrier.oldLayout = vkImageLayout_; // imageLayout_
    barrier.newLayout = newLayout;
    barrier.srcQueueFamilyIndex = VK_QUEUE_FAMILY_IGNORED;
    barrier.dstQueueFamilyIndex = VK_QUEUE_FAMILY_IGNORED;
    barrier.image = image_;
    barrier.subresourceRange.aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT;
    barrier.subresourceRange.baseMipLevel = 0;
    barrier.subresourceRange.levelCount = 1;
    barrier.subresourceRange.baseArrayLayer = 0;
    barrier.subresourceRange.layerCount = 1;

    VkPipelineStageFlags sourceStage;
    VkPipelineStageFlags destinationStage;

    if (vkImageLayout_ == VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED && newLayout == VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL) {
        barrier.srcAccessMask = 0;
        barrier.dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_TRANSFER_WRITE_BIT;

        sourceStage = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TOP_OF_PIPE_BIT;
        destinationStage = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT;
    }
    else if (vkImageLayout_ == VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL && newLayout == VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL) {
        barrier.srcAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_TRANSFER_WRITE_BIT;
        barrier.dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_SHADER_READ_BIT;

        sourceStage = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT;
        destinationStage = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_FRAGMENT_SHADER_BIT;
    }
    else {
        throw std::invalid_argument("unsupported layout transition!");
    }

    vkCmdPipelineBarrier(
        commandBuffer,
        sourceStage, destinationStage,
        0,
        0, nullptr,
        0, nullptr,
        1, &barrier
    );

    commandPool.endSingleTimeCommands(commandBuffer); // endSingleTimeCommands(commandBuffer);
    vkImageLayout_ = newLayout;
}


void VulkanImage::copyImageToImage(const VulkanImage & sourceImage, const VulkanCommandPool &commandPool, VkFilter filter)
{
    VkImageBlit vkImgBlit = {};
    vkImgBlit.srcSubresource.aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT;
    vkImgBlit.srcSubresource.baseArrayLayer = 0;
    vkImgBlit.srcSubresource.layerCount = 1; // number of layers to copy, must be > 0
    vkImgBlit.srcSubresource.mipLevel = 0;
    vkImgBlit.srcOffsets[1].x = sourceImage.imageInfo_.extent.width;
    vkImgBlit.srcOffsets[1].y = sourceImage.imageInfo_.extent.height;
    //vkImgBlit.srcOffsets[0].z;
    vkImgBlit.dstSubresource.aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT;
    vkImgBlit.dstSubresource.baseArrayLayer = 0;
    vkImgBlit.dstSubresource.layerCount = 1;
    vkImgBlit.dstSubresource.mipLevel = 0;
    vkImgBlit.dstOffsets[1].x = imageInfo_.extent.width;
    vkImgBlit.dstOffsets[1].y = imageInfo_.extent.height;

    auto commandBuffer = commandPool.beginSingleTimeCommands();
    vkCmdBlitImage(commandBuffer, sourceImage.handle(), sourceImage.getImageLayout(), image_, vkImageLayout_, 1, &vkImgBlit, filter);
    commandPool.endSingleTimeCommands(commandBuffer);
}


VkCommandBuffer VulkanCommandPool::beginSingleTimeCommands() const
{
    VkCommandBufferAllocateInfo allocInfo = {};
    allocInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_COMMAND_BUFFER_ALLOCATE_INFO;
    allocInfo.level = VK_COMMAND_BUFFER_LEVEL_PRIMARY;
    allocInfo.commandPool = commandPool_;
    allocInfo.commandBufferCount = 1;

    VkCommandBuffer commandBuffer;
    vkAllocateCommandBuffers(logicalDevice_->handle(), &allocInfo, &commandBuffer);

    VkCommandBufferBeginInfo beginInfo = {};
    beginInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_COMMAND_BUFFER_BEGIN_INFO;
    beginInfo.flags = VK_COMMAND_BUFFER_USAGE_ONE_TIME_SUBMIT_BIT;

    vkBeginCommandBuffer(commandBuffer, &beginInfo);

    return commandBuffer;
}

void VulkanCommandPool::endSingleTimeCommands(VkCommandBuffer commandBuffer) const
{
    vkEndCommandBuffer(commandBuffer);

    VkSubmitInfo submitInfo = {};
    submitInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SUBMIT_INFO;
    submitInfo.commandBufferCount = 1;
    submitInfo.pCommandBuffers = &commandBuffer;

    vkQueueSubmit(logicalDevice_->getGraphicsQueue(), 1, &submitInfo, VK_NULL_HANDLE);
    vkQueueWaitIdle(logicalDevice_->getGraphicsQueue());

    vkFreeCommandBuffers(logicalDevice_->handle(), commandPool_, 1, &commandBuffer);
}
```

**Store image for drawing later**

```
void GuiImages::push_back(GuiTexture &&texture)
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(texturesMutex_);
    textures_.push_back(std::move(texture));
}
```

**Code Snipet: Draws textures using imgui later**

```
std::vector<ImTextureID> imTextureIDs;
for (auto & it : textures_)
    imTextureIDs.push_back(it.getImGuiTexture());


for (int i = 0; i < textures_.size(); ++i)
    {
        float last_button_x2 = ImGui::GetItemRectMax().x;
        float window_visible_x2 = ImGui::GetWindowPos().x + ImGui::GetWindowContentRegionMax().x;

        if (i != 0 && (last_button_x2 + tbnailSize) < window_visible_x2) 
            ImGui::SameLine();

        ImGui::PushID(i);

        if (ImGui::ImageButton(imTextureIDs[i], ImVec2(tbnailSize, tbnailSize), ImVec2(0, 0), ImVec2(1, 1), 0, ImColor(0, 0, 0)))
        {
            parent_->guiCanvas().setTexture(GuiTexture(parent_->logicalDevice(), parent_->physicalDevice(), parent_->commandPool(), textures_[i].getFilePath()));
        }

        //std::cout << ImGui::IsItemVisible();

        ImGui::PopID();
    }
```

Comment: What does you current implementation look like?

Comment: @Ted, There's quite allot of code, I put up most of the related code

Comment: GFX applications tend to be rather large so it is understandable that mcve is supposed to be huge. But from the given code it is not possible to figure out anything. For example what happens in `parent_->guiImage().push_back(std::move(smallImage));`? What is `parent`? `guiImage` seems to return a non-const reference to container of some sort?  How are you using images added into that container?

Comment: @VTT that line of code simply stores smallImage in a container, where it can be referenced to be drawn later. The crash will occur even if I comment out this line. (meaning images are uploaded to the GPU but not drawn

Comment: @VTT added the code you referenced

Comment: I just want to know in general what is the best way to do something like this. I suppose the naive way would be to use cpu side synchronization like std::mutex to ensure that image uploading only happens when the main loop is not running

Comment: Sometimes "naive" is best when it comes to thread synch. If you can't reason clearly about your synchronization methodology, you're not likely to understand the hidden pitfalls inherent in (all) multithreaded setups. Therefore, prefer "naive" techniques you understand to "expert" techniques you don't IMO.

Comment: Part that draws textures does not acquire lock as you do in `GuiImages::push_back` `std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(texturesMutex_);` so you are getting a race condition. Also i'm not sure whether imgui calls work properly when used in multithreaded manner.

Comment: @VTT I do acquire the lock, there's just allot of gui code and I only posted the relevant snippet. The issue i have is with synchronization of the main loop and the image uploading, I have the drawing part commented out for now (works fine single threaded though)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I record command buffers in the main loop and also in the image uploading process. What kind of synchronization is needed to allow this?

Make sure each thread uses its own command buffer pool. And that only one thread at a time can submit to each queue. This means in your case a mutex around `vkQueueSubmit` and `vkQueueWaitIdle`.

```
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(logicalDevice_->getGraphicsQueueMutex());
    vkQueueSubmit(logicalDevice_->getGraphicsQueue(), 1, &submitInfo, VK_NULL_HANDLE);
    vkQueueWaitIdle(logicalDevice_->getGraphicsQueue());
}
```

though it's better to use a fence to wait on it if you really need to wait right now:

```
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(logicalDevice_->getGraphicsQueueMutex());
    vkQueueSubmit(logicalDevice_->getGraphicsQueue(), 1, &submitInfo, fence_);
}
vkWaitForFences(logicalDevice_->handle(), 1, &fence_, TRUE, ~uint64_t(0));
vkResetFences(logicalDevice_->handle(), 1, &fence_); //reset for next use
```

or make the calling code pass the fence if it needs to wait.

You also need to synchronize access to `textures_` on the main thread.

---

To comment on your code in general:

**Batch your commands!**

There is no reason to split the transition->copy->transition into 3 *separate* commands with waitIdle after each submit.

Instead put it in a single command buffer and use a Transfer capable queue for that. Then add a semaphore to sync it against usage in the main queue.

```
auto cmdBuffer = commandPool.beginSingleTimeCommands();
vulkanImage_.transitionImageLayout(cmdBuffer , VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL); // transitionImageLayout(textureImage, VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL);
vulkanImage_.copyImageToImage(sourceImage, cmdBuffer, VK_FILTER_NEAREST);
vulkanImage_.transitionImageLayout(cmdBuffer, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL); //transitionImageLayout(textureImage, VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL);
commandPool.endSingleTimeCommands(commandBuffer, &semaphore);
```

On first use of the semaphore in the graphics thread you set the semaphore member to null and recycle it to signal the sync already happened.

Or you use a fence to wait on it before using it in another command buffer.